# Need help correcting this VB.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim dbBorrow As Double
    dbBorrow = txtBorrow.Text
    If dbBorrow < 500000 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Lowest Amount which can be borrow is RS.500000")
    ElseIf dbBorrow > 7000000 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Maximum amount which can be borrowed is RS.7000000")
    ElseIf dbBorrow = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Pls Enter the amount you want to borrow")
```

My question says that if i want to obtain a loan the val should be inbetween 500000 and 7000000, so if its less than 500000 then i used a message box to say the loan cannot be obtain i used the same thing for more than 70000000. but if the textbox is left empty i wanted to display a message saying pls enter a val. i tried this error appears "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: `dbBorrow` is a double. `txtBorrow.Text` is a string.  you need to use `Double.TryParse` to convert the numerals in the text box to actual numbers.  Also judging from the error message, there is no Text in that textbox

Comment: You need to switch option strict on first

Comment: Obvious duplicate of [need with this code VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933621/need-with-this-code-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing strings and double. You should enable option strict on, this will help you understand what is happening.

If you properly convert your string to a double, you can set your double to NaN if it's not a valid number (this won't just work for empty string, but also work if you write letters).

```
Dim dbBorrow As Double

If Not Double.TryParse(txtBorrow.Text, dbBorrow) Then
    dbBorrow = Double.NaN
End If

If dbBorrow < 500000 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Lowest Amount which can be borrow is RS.500000")
ElseIf dbBorrow > 7000000 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Maximum amount which can be borrowed is RS.7000000")
ElseIf Double.IsNaN(dbBorrow) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Pls Enter the amount you want to borrow")
Else
    ' ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments to your code please see below... Using the TryParse will not thrown an exception when not a double, it would return false...

```
 Dim dbBorrow As Double = 0
 If Double.TryParse(txtBorrow.Text, dbBorrow) Then
  If dbBorrow < 500000 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Lowest Amount which can be borrow is RS.500000")
  ElseIf dbBorrow > 7000000 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Maximum amount which can be borrowed is RS.7000000") 
  End If     
 Else
     MessageBox.Show("Pls Enter the amount you want to borrow")
 End If
```